# Returning a borrow from an owned resource

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function that maps an `Arc<[T]>` into an `Iterable`, for use with `flat_map` (that is, I want to call `i.flat_map(my_iter)` for some other `i: Iterator<Item=Arc<[T]>>`).

```
fn my_iter<'a, T>(n: Arc<[T]>) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
    let t: &'a [T] = &*n.clone();
    t.into_iter()
}
```

The function above does not work because `n.clone()` produces an owned value of type `Arc<[T]>`, which I can dereference to `[T]` and then borrow to get `&[T]`, but the lifetime of the borrow only lasts until the end of the function, while the `'a` lifetime lasts until the client drops the returned iterator.

How do I clone the `Arc` in such a way that the client takes ownership of the clone, so that the value is only dropped after the client is done with the iterator (assuming no one else is using the `Arc`)?

---

Here's some sample code for the source iterator:

```
struct BaseIter<T>(Arc<[T]>);

impl<T> Iterator for BaseIter<T> {
    type Item = Arc<[T]>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.0.clone())
    }
}
```

How do I implement the result of `BaseIter(data).flat_map(my_iter)` (which is of type `Iterator<&T>`) given that `BaseIter` is *producing* data, not just borrowing it? (The real thing is more complicated than this, it's not always the same result, but the ownership semantics are the same.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this. Remember, lifetimes in Rust are purely compile-time entities and are only used to validate that your code doesn't accidentally access dropped data. For example:

```
fn my_iter<'a, T>(n: Arc<[T]>) -> slice::Iter<'a, T>
```

Here `'a` does not "last until the client drops the returned iterator"; this reasoning is incorrect. From the point of view of `slice::Iter` its lifetime parameter means the lifetime *of the slice it is pointing at*; from the point of view of `my_iter` `'a` is just a lifetime parameter which can be chosen *arbitrarily* by the caller. In other words, `slice::Iter` is always tied to some slice with some *concrete* lifetime, but the signature of `my_iter` states that it is able to return *arbitrary* lifetime. Do you see the contradiction?

As a side note, due to covariance of lifetimes you can return a slice of a *static* slice from such a function:

```
static DATA: &'static [u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

fn get_data<'a>() -> &'a [u8] {
    DATA
}
```

The above definition compiles, but it only works because `DATA` is stored in static memory of your program and is *always* valid when your program is running; this is not so with `Arc<[T]>`.

`Arc<[T]>` implies *shared ownership*, that is, the data inside `Arc<[T]>` is jointly owned by all clones of the original `Arc<[T]>` value. Therefore, when the last clone of an `Arc` goes out of scope, the value it contains is dropped, and the respective memory is freed. Now, consider what would happen if `my_iter()` was allowed to compile:

```
let iter = {
    let data: Arc<[i32]> = get_arc_slice();
    my_iter(data.clone())
};
iter.map(|x| x+1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Because in `my_iter()` `'a` can be arbitrary and is not linked in any way to `Arc<[T]>` (and can not be, actually), nothing prevents this code from compilation - the user might as well choose `'static` lifetime. However, here all clones of `data` will be dropped inside the block, and the array it contains inside will be freed. Using `iter` after the block is unsafe because it now provides access to the freed memory.

> How do I clone the Arc in such a way that the client takes ownership of the clone, so that the value is only dropped after the client is done with the iterator (assuming no one else is using the Arc)?

So, as follows from the above, this is impossible. Only the *owner* of the data determines when this data should be destroyed, and borrowed references (whose existence is always implied by lifetime parameters) may only borrow the data for the time when it exists, but borrows *cannot* affect when and how the data is destroyed. In order for borrowed references to compile, they need to always borrow only the data which is valid through the whole time these references are active.

What you can do is to rethink your architecture. It is hard to say what exactly can be done without looking at the full code, but in the case of this particular example you can, for example, first collect the iterator into a vector and then iterate over the vector:

```
let items: Vec<_> = your_iter.collect();
items.iter().flat_map(my_iter)
```

Note that now `my_iter()` should indeed accept `&Arc<[T]>`, just as Francis Gagné has suggested; this way, the lifetimes of the output iterator will be tied to the lifetime of the input reference, and everything should work fine, because now it is guaranteed that `Arc`s are stored stably in the vector for their later perusal during the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for this enlightening writeup, which helped me fix the issue. I realized I was very much overusing `Arc` in this case; iterators should not use `Arc` because they do not take ownership of the data - the client already owns the `data` field, and the iterators should just borrow from that. (My data structure is a kind of binary tree with shared children, so I think `Arc` is still appropriate for the child links in the data structure, but iterators over it should not take control of the data.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, yep, your summary is correct. Iterators take ownership of the data they yield afterwards only when the original structure is consumed, like with `Vec::into_iter()`, otherwise references are more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to make this work by passing an `Arc<[T]>` by value. You need to start from a reference to an `Arc<[T]>` in order to construct a valid `slice::Iter`.

```
fn my_iter<'a, T>(n: &'a Arc<[T]>) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
    n.into_iter()
}
```

Or, if we elide the lifetimes:

```
fn my_iter<T>(n: &Arc<[T]>) -> slice::Iter<T> {
    n.into_iter()
}
```

Comment: Hmm, well that's a problem. I have to use `Arc<[T]>` as the input, because it is coming from an `Iterator<Item=Arc<[T]>>`. I can't really change this to  `Iterator<Item=&Arc<[T]>>` because the source is creating the values by cloning subslices from an immutable backing vector, and letting them go, relying on the `Arc` to clean up the backing vector when it runs out of references. Using `&Arc<[T]>` this way seems to just push the issue down the road.

Comment: I added some code for the source iterator. How would you modify it to produce `&Arc<[T]>` data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another iterator as return type of the function `my_iter`. `slice::Iter<'a, T>` has an associated type `Item = &'a T`. You need an iterator with associated type `Item = T`. Something like `vec::IntoIter<T>`. You can implement such an iterator yourself:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct BaseIter<T>(Arc<[T]>);

impl<T> Iterator for BaseIter<T> {
    type Item = Arc<[T]>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(self.0.clone())
    }
}

struct ArcIntoIter<T>(usize, Arc<[T]>);

impl<T:Clone> Iterator for ArcIntoIter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.0 < self.1.len(){
            let i = self.0;
            self.0+=1;
            Some(self.1[i].clone())
        }else{
            None
        }    
    }
}

fn my_iter<T>(n: Arc<[T]>) -> ArcIntoIter<T> {
    ArcIntoIter(0, n)
}

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(["A","B","C"]);
    println!("{:?}", BaseIter(data).take(3).flat_map(my_iter).collect::<String>());
    //output:"ABCABCABC"
}
```